# Оптимизация работы подзапросов

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте! Друзья, столкнулся со следующим вопросом.
Есть запрос:

`SELECT ol.id, 
IF(ol.id_user = 0, ol.name,
      (SELECT user.name
       FROM USER
       WHERE id = ol.id_user)) AS name_user
FROM order_list ol
WHERE ol.status = 0
ORDER BY ol.id DESC`

Как видите, он возвращает id и name_user (которое берется в зависимости от условия). В случае ложности конструкции IF происходит подзапрос который возвращает имя пользователя из таблицы user. Но что делать если мне нужно получить еще и поля `phone`, `email` и тд. из таблицы user? Логично предположить, что можно просто дополнить запрос еще конструкциями IF и подзапросами, например:

`SELECT ol.id,
       IF(ol.id_user = 0, ol.name,
            (SELECT user.name
             FROM USER
             WHERE id = ol.id_user)) AS name_user,
       IF(ol.id_user = 0, "phone",
            (SELECT user.phone_number
             FROM USER
             WHERE id = ol.id_user)) AS phone_user,
       IF(ol.id_user = 0, "email",
            (SELECT user.email
             FROM USER
             WHERE id = ol.id_user)) AS email_user
FROM order_list ol
WHERE ol.status = 0
ORDER BY ol.id DESC`

Но это жутко затратно, как результат по мере разрастания данных в таблицах запрос будет выполнятся все дольше и дольше.

Как можно более элегантно решить данную проблему, подскажите пожалуйста.

Кст, было бы круто, если можно было бы как то вытащить подзапросом нужные (несколько) атрибутов и поместить их в одну переменную.

К примеру,

`SELECT ol.id, 
IF(ol.id_user = 0, ol.name,
      (SELECT user.name, user.phone, user.email
       FROM USER
       WHERE id = ol.id_user)) AS data_user
FROM order_list ol
WHERE ol.status = 0
ORDER BY ol.id DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Дошел к ответу сам :)
Данный запрос можно реализовать с помощью LEFT JOIN

`SELECT ol.id AS orderId,
       ol.id_user AS userId,
       IF(u.name IS NULL, ol.name, u.name) AS userName
FROM order_list ol
LEFT JOIN USER u ON ol.id_user = u.id`

Comment: Вместо `IF(u.name IS NULL, ol.name, u.name)` можно написать `IFNULL(u.name, ol.name)`. Если полей/выражений больше двух, то можно `IFNULL` заменить на `COALESCE`.